# How to call REST java webservice from non Java scripts

Tags: java, c++, c, web-services, rest

I have a simple webservice Java/REST/Jersey that responds to sql requests.

```
Employee{first,last,SS,address,phone..}
../REST/getEmployee ---> returns Employee as JSON/JSONArray
```

MyQuestion: How do I save an Employee if called from Non-Java languages like C, C++?

```
Employee e {mike,smith,main st, 111-222-9999,..}
../REST/saveEmployee
```

Comment: The servers's language is irrelevant. Just use language-specific JSON - libs for the clients.

Comment: c++?  [casablanca](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: @Fildor, Thanks. I didn't realize C had JSON client libraries.